# Reading 64-bit integer from binary file in Matlab does not give the correct result

Tags: matlab

Edit: Problem was that even specifying the precision of the inputs matlab still converts them to doubles unless you specify otherwise. My mistake.

Reading a simple 64 bit integer into matlab appears to be giving a different value than if I do the conversion in python or windows calculator.

I have a small file, 8 bytes long whose contents are

```
0x99, 0x1e, 0x6b, 0x40, 0x27, 0xe3, 0x01, 0x56
```

I use the following in matlab:

```
fid = fopen('test.data')
input = fread(fid, 1, 'int64')
```

I get

```
input = 6197484319962505200
```

However, using either python or the windows calculator I get a different decimal representation for `0x5601e327406b1e99`. Both predict I should get
`input = 6197484319962504857` (which is different by 343). Its obviously not an endianness issue as then it would be WAY off.

I originally was led to test this because reading doubles from a large binary file was giving odd results. I then tried just reading them in as integers and comparing by hand.

My question is, am I doing something wrong, is there something I am overlooking, or is matlab making an error here? I am using win64 matlab R2010a.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `fread` is actually reading it in as a double:

```
>> class(input)

ans =

  double
```

Because the number is so large, that's presumably the closest double value.

It works for me if I manually specify that the matlab variable should be `int64`, in addition to specifying the type in the source file (see [the documentation for `fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html)):

```
>> input = fread(fid, 1, '*int64')

input =

  6197484319962504857
```

Comment: Right, `fread` is documented as converting all values to `double` unless you specify otherwise.